# Print the files that find acts on

Tags: find

I use the following command in order to delete only the files that start with `DBG` and older then two day , but this syntax not print the files that deleted

```bash
find /tmp  -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -exec rm {} \;
```

How to add to this the find syntax , the print in order to print the deleted files?

Comment: Why don't you use `rm -v`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `-print` flag:

```bash
find /tmp  -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -exec rm {} \; -print
```

or, if `rm` supports the `-v` option, let `rm` do it all:

```bash
find /tmp  -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -exec rm -v {} +
```

or if your `find` supports `-delete`:

```bash
find /tmp  -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -delete -print
```

(note that [the first two have a race condition that could allow one to delete `DBG*` files anywhere on the file system](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html#Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec))

Comment: `-print -exec rm {} \;` prints the names of files which could not be deleted, too.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Yeah, of course. I intended to edit it when I went back home, but Stephane did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple immediate options:

```bash
find /tmp  -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -exec echo {} \; -delete
```

or

```bash
find /tmp  -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -exec echo {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

use `-printf` and `%p`

```bash
find /tmp -type f -mtime +2 -name "DBG*" -delete -printf "operate on file %p\n"
```

Comment: this would print all files in `/tmp`, regardless of age or name. The difference between `-print` and `-printf` shouldn't mean much here.